# How to not print the path in user@user:path$ in my terminal

Tags: linux

When I'm working inside a directory in my console, this line
`user@user:/a/very/very/very/very/long/path$` is disturbing me. Is there a way to minimize or delete the path from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the `$PS1` variable to your liking. See *PROMPTING* in `man bash` for details. For example, using `\W` instead of `\w` would show only the name of the current directory, not the whole path.

```
export PS1='\u@\h:\W\$'
```

Save the line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to apply the configuration to every newly started session.

Answer (score 2):

Simply export the `PS1` env variable to what you want to display, example :

```
export PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):'
```

If you want this to be permanent, make sure to configure it in `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`.